# Tensorflow: how to obtain intermediate cell states (c) from LSTMCell using dynamic_rnn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

By default, function `dynamic_rnn` outputs only hidden states (known as `m`) for each time point which can be obtained as follows:

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(100)
rnn_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,
                                   inputs=inputs,
                                   sequence_length=sequence_lengths,
                                   dtype=tf.float32)
```

Is there a way get intermediate (not final) cell states (`c`) in addition?

A `tensorflow` contributor [mentions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9995#issuecomment-343641550) that it can be done with a cell wrapper:

```
class Wrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
  def __init__(self, inner_cell):
     super(Wrapper, self).__init__()
     self._inner_cell = inner_cell
  @property
  def state_size(self):
     return self._inner_cell.state_size
  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return (self._inner_cell.state_size, self._inner_cell.output_size)
  def call(self, input, state)
    output, next_state = self._inner_cell(input, state)
    emit_output = (next_state, output)
    return emit_output, next_state
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed solution works for me, but `Layer.call` method spec is more general, so the following `Wrapper` should be more robust to API changes. Thy this:

```py
class Wrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
  def __init__(self, inner_cell):
     super(Wrapper, self).__init__()
     self._inner_cell = inner_cell

  @property
  def state_size(self):
     return self._inner_cell.state_size

  @property
  def output_size(self):
    return (self._inner_cell.state_size, self._inner_cell.output_size)

  def call(self, input, *args, **kwargs):
    output, next_state = self._inner_cell(input, *args, **kwargs)
    emit_output = (next_state, output)
    return emit_output, next_state
```

Here's the test:

```py
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
basic_cell = Wrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons, state_is_tuple=False))
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
print(outputs, states)

X_batch = np.array([
  # t = 0      t = 1
  [[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]], # instance 0
  [[3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0]], # instance 1
  [[6, 7, 8], [6, 5, 4]], # instance 2
  [[9, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1]], # instance 3
])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  outputs_val = outputs[0].eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch})
  print(outputs_val)
```

Returned `outputs` is the tuple of `(?, 2, 10)` and `(?, 2, 5)` tensors, which are all LSTM states and outputs. Note that I'm using the "graduated" version of `LSTMCell`, from `tf.nn.rnn_cell` package, not `tf.contrib.rnn`. Also note `state_is_tuple=True` to avoid dealing with `LSTMStateTuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Maxim's idea, I ended up with the following solution:

```
class StatefulLSTMCell(LSTMCell):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StatefulLSTMCell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def output_size(self):
        return (self.state_size, super(StatefulLSTMCell, self).output_size)

    def call(self, input, state):
        output, next_state = super(StatefulLSTMCell, self).call(input, state)
        emit_output = (next_state, output)
        return emit_output, next_state
```