# Cell state in DA-RNN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to implement the DA-RNN in this [paper](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2017/0366.pdf). The page 3 of the research paper talks about the encoder network. Specifically I want to implement the following equations :

[image]

I want to confirm that in the above equation I require cell state `s` at every timestep ? Usually in RNNs we just need the cell state from the previous timestep. So what I mean is if we have a batch of 5 timestamps we use the hidden state `h` at all timesteps from `1 to 5` and we use cell state `s` from only the 5th timestep (and not for all the timesteps).

The `out,s = dynamic_rnn` function in tensorflow also gives me this output where `out` will have hidden states computed at each timestep and `s` will be a tuple of `c` and `h` at the last timestep. For example if my input is of the size `batch_size x max_timestep x num_features` and lets say `max_timestep=5` then `s.c` and `s.h` will consist of cell state and hidden state from the 5th timestep and not for timesteps `1,2,3,4`. However in the paper the general notation is cell state `s` at time `t-1`. So if we are talking about 5 timesteps we need cell state `s` at timesteps `1,2,3,4` which I can't obtain thru `dynamic_rnn` function.

So to summarise

1. is my assumption correct that I need cell state `s` for all the timesteps to implement above equation in the image ?
2. If yes how can i do this in tensorflow ? Should I write my own LSTM wrapper ?

Update :

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745027/tensorflow-how-to-obtain-intermediate-cell-states-c-from-lstmcell-using-dynam) resolved my issue. I turns out there is no direct function to obtain cell states at each timestep however we can wrap the RNN cell and just give it as input to the `dynamicRNN` function in tf.

Comment: I can answer yes for the first question. I recommend you refer to the decoding/training/evaluate part of  [Neural Machine Translation with Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention) if you want to do this in tensorflow.

Comment: @giser_yugang thanks for the reply. I went through the link and found out that the type of attention in `seq2seq` models don't use the cell state `c` in any of the computations. In their notations `c` means context vector. So in the end i guess everyone gives different kind of inputs to an `mlp` net which they call attention model. Anyway i think there is no way to get `c` which is cell state vector at everytimestep.